# Are mutually exclusive events are independent events?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

So far my understanding:
consider two mutually exclusive events, A and B. If A occurs, B cannot, and vice versa. In this case, the occurrence of one event (say, A) provides certain information about the other event (B). Therefore, they are dependent.

Please describe?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.  What do you want us to describe?  (Also, there seems to be a typo in your title question).

Answer (score 1):

The events say A and B are mutually exclusive means that they can't occur simultaneously i.e. p(A $\cap$ B) =0.Mutual independence requires p(A $\cap$ B)=p(A)*p(B). So mutually exclusive events are independent only if for one of them probability of occurrence is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm I may be wrong but let's say you have a "high-tech" coin for gambling: you simply do the coin flipping and you get either Head (H) or Tail (T) - apparently the two events are mutual exclusive.

But now, since this is a high-tech coin it allows you to cheat: there is a microcomputer and rotor inside to detect which side it lands, and after a few rounds it will start the motor to interfere with the flipping - if the current result is T, the cheating system will try its best to guarantee the next flipping is H.

You see here the events of which side the coin lands are still mutual exclusive but they are not independent.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Because you posit a *sequence* of coin flips, could you please explain what *events* "H" and "T" might designate?  (Your description seems to use the term "event" as if you meant "outcome.")

Comment: To clarify: the difficulty I am facing in trying to understand this example is that the event "the first flip is H" and the event "the second flip H" are *not* the same event, even though their descriptions have something in common.  They cannot possibly be modeled as the same event in a probability space because their probabilities can differ!